# Get Simple CMS - Control Page Content

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I am using a CMS where adding page content is easy:

```
<div>
  <?php get_page_content(); ?>
</div>
```

...which will spit out any and everything from the body of the CMS admin edit page.

But what about when I want to add and control smaller bits? For example, employee bio's on a company team page. http://get-simple.info/start/team/

In HTML I would do something like:

```
<div id="employees-bios">
  <div class="employee">
    <img src="employee1.jpg">
    <p>Employee is a seasoned designer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="employee">
    <img src="employee2.jpg">
    <p>Employee is a seasoned architect.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to look into components? Would this be done similar to how sidebars are implemented in GetSimple CMS?